# Why does jQuery return integer instead of object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to preselect an option in a `<select>` tag based on a variable.
However, when selecting the elements via jQuery and iterating on it with .each() it seems to be returning integers instead of objects, so .value etc. are not applicable.

this is my code:

```
$("#id option").each(function(option){
    if(option.value == "myValue") {
        option.value.selected = "true";
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `each` function is incorrect if you want the element reference then there should be second parameter in `each` as first parameter is the `index` reference parameter. Secondly, you can simply use the `val()` function to set the value of the dropdown.

```js
$("#id option").each(function(index,option){
    if(option.value == "myValue") {
        $("#id").val('myValue');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id'>
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="myValue">myValue</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or you can simply use `$(this)` as:

```js
$("#id option").each(function(){
    //check value of each option
    if($(this).val() == "myValue") {
        $("#id").val('myValue');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id'>
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="myValue">myValue</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @JacekZawisza glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for jQuery's `each` is the *index*, not the object. Try this instead:

```
$("#id option").each(function(i, option){
```

(if you don't care for the index `i`, feel free not to use it, but if you want to use the value, you have to include an argument for the index first)

The native array iteration methods use a more sensible approach and list the element in question first, for example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id option').forEach((option) =>
```

So you have to keep careful track of which method you're using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this)` inside for get each item

```
$("#id option").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: IMO code is more readable if you avoid the `this` keyword when it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well just add index in your code

```
$("#id option").each(function(index, option){
```

Since each function takes 2 param index and object, if you add only 1 it will treat as first parameter ie index.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in the callback function for `each` is the index and the second is the element.

```
$("#id option").each(function(index, option){
if(option.value == "myValue") {
    option.value.selected = "true";
}
});
```